# reloading section of UITableView in ios

Tags: ios, uitableview, cell, sections, reloading

I have 4 sections in tableview.
I am reloading section using :

```
[self.tableview reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:1] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

What happens, when i observe cells in section 2 and my code runs to reload section 1; tableView position gets up.
I want tableView position to be maintained, when any section in table is reloading.At the same time, I don't want any animation for tableview, when table is reloading.
Thanks!

Comment: If your table is scrolling after reloading the section, just use row animation "UITableViewRowAnimationNone" with reloadSections method.

Comment: @Shardul : i am using same row animation only; but it still animating.

Comment: I got solution, as i am using the cell sized tableviewCells, i need to implement estimatedRowHeight() delegate method. And need to specify the  approx. cell height for each section.  This helps me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try below Code:

```
        [self.tableView beginUpdates];

             NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, 1);//Your section number instead of 1
             NSIndexSet *section = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:range];
             [self.tableView reloadSections:section withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

        [self.tableView endUpdates];
```

Comment: Still not working.Table get shift it's position and animation is also there, while reloading.

Comment: try with `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{});` block

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)reloadSections:(NSIndexSet *)sections withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation
```